# fseek() on text files in C language

Tags: c, file, fseek, file-pointer

I'm starting to learng C and i'm using text files. Loading text from them, work with it and then updating it in the same file. I was told that fseek() is not guaranteed to work everytime in text files, and i can't truly understand why. If someone could explain this it would be great!!

I also found that if you do

```
pos = ftell(file);
fseek(pos);
```

it's guaranteed to move the pointer to "pos". Is this right?

Comment: You should read the documentation for the library functions fseek and ftell. Also, you should include real code (that's not how you call fseek).

Comment: Ignacio Romero,`fseek()` works for the beginning, end of file and to a previous place from `ftell()`.  It does not work with computed offsets from these 3 places.  For more detail, best to review the C spec.

Comment: @IgnacioRomero: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica *For more detail, best to review the C spec* [Indeed](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268):  "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has **undefined behavior for a binary stream** ...", and [then](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2): "The `ftell` function obtains the current value of the file position indicator ... For a text stream ... **the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read**"

Comment: (cont) I have no idea why `fseek()`/`ftell()` is taught so widely as a way to get the size of a file.  It only works because an implementation goes beyond the C standard.  For example, POSIX says the return from `ftell()` is a byte offset.  Windows does for binary streams, too, but doesn't for text streams.  `fstat(fileno(fp), &sb)` and then reading `sb.st_size` is probably [*more* portable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fstat-fstat32-fstat64-fstati64-fstat32i64-fstat64i32?view=msvc-160) than `fseek()`/`ftell()`.

Comment: Nevermind that relying on the resulting size [is a TOCTOU bug anyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).

Comment: @AndrewHenle "no idea why fseek()/ftell() is taught so widely as a way to get the size of a file." --> it is a hack that overwhelmingly "works" - except when it doesn't - and there is not great alternative.  The "right" answer is to code a solution that does not need the file length.

Answer (score 1):

> I was told that `fseek()` is not guaranteed to work every time in text files.

This is true, but an explanation is required:

Some legacy systems use multiple bytes to encode the end of line in text files, or some other scheme such as fixed length records... This makes file offsets differ from the number of bytes read from the stream. In fact, some file offsets are meaningless in text files, such as the offset of the `LF` byte in a `CR`/`LF` sequence.  This feature is also a problem when writing text files and is more so in update mode when using the same stream pointer to read and write to the same file.

This was never a problem on Unix systems where text files and binary files are just sequences of bytes and line endings represented by a single newline byte.

When porting the C language to other operating systems, compiler vendors came up with various elaborate tricks to handle the translation of system specific line endings to a single `'\n'` byte.

As these tricks where system specific or even vendor specific, no standard approach could be standardized in 1989 when the ANSI drafted the first C Standard. They just agreed on the `b` flag for the `fopen()` mode argument and removed any constraint on the meaning of the return value of `ftell()` beyond simple constraints:

> **C19 7.21.9.2 The `fseek` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `fseek` function sets the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by `stream`. If a read or write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and `fseek` fails.
>
> For a binary stream, the new position, measured in characters from the beginning of the file, is obtained by adding `offset` to the position specified by `whence`. The specified position is the beginning of the file if `whence` is `SEEK_SET`, the current value of the file position indicator if `SEEK_CUR`, or end-of-file if `SEEK_END`. A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a `whence` value of `SEEK_END`.
>
> For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file and `whence` shall be `SEEK_SET`.

Note that `fseek(pos);` in your question is incorrect as the stream and whence argument are missing. You should write:

```
long pos = ftell(file);
...
fseek(file, pos, SEEK_SET);  // move back to position <pos>
```

Note however that `fseek()` can fail for other reasons: not all streams support seeking, such as pipes, terminal connections and other character devices... File offsets may exceed the range of type `long`, especially on legacy systems, `fgetpos()` / `fsetpos()` is a preferred alternative if available.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i get an idea of what's happening then. I'll try using the fseek as intended then

Comment: "They just agreed on the t and b flags for the fopen() mode argument" --> I do not see a `'t'` flag in the C spec.  Perhaps that is some implementation extension.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: good point. The `t` flag is just another Microsoft extension to select text mode handling for a new stream when the default translation mode is set to binary via `_set_fmode()` or the global variable `_fmode` ( cf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/text-and-binary-mode-file-i-o?view=msvc-160 ...) It is amazing how much energy has been wasted for the last 40 years keeping the original CP/M convention alive. [RIP Gary Kildall.](https://computerhistory.org/blog/early-digital-research-cpm-source-code/)

Comment: @chqrlie Since 1870s, we are stuck with [QWERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#History).  Some design choices continue to haunt

Answer (score 0):

Ffseek() is used to move file pointer associated with a given file to a specific position.syntax :fseek(FILE *pointer, long int offset, int position),offset: number of bytes to offset from position , position: position from where offset is added.
position defines the point with respect to which the file pointer needs to be moved. It has three values:
SEEK_END : It denotes end of the file.
SEEK_SET : It denotes starting of the file.
SEEK_CUR : It denotes file pointer’s current position.
 // Moving pointer to end
We need to specify postion
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    // Printing position of pointer

printf("%ld", ftell(fp));
What the thing you have return is also write but specifiying offset position is much better